# Magento 2: Use Zend_Pdf easily while making PDF file

Tags: magento2.3, phtml, pdf, zend-framework, zend

How to make a dynamic PDF easily while sending an email with this PDF attachment using Zend_Pdf because of this type of code

```
 $page->drawText(__("Image"), $x + 60, $this->y-10, 'UTF-8');
 $page->drawText(__("Sku"), $x + 200, $this->y-10, 'UTF-8');
 $page->drawText(__("Name"), $x + 310, $this->y-10, 'UTF-8');
```

It is very complicated.
how to convert this in a table format?

Or can we call phtml while making PDF file?